# How to include python libraries required to execute program with submission?

Tags: python

I understand that this has likely been posted before but my Google searches could not find exactly what I wanted, so if an answer already exists please link to it.

I have a python program which requires pygame to be imported, I need to submit this program as a file, how can I include pygame and any other future modules in a local path so I can zip the entire project with all modules and my actual code so when it is unzipped it runs without requiring the user to install these modules on their machine manually?

Thanks

Comment: Is py2exe the best way?

Comment: I had some success with PyInstaller, but did never try pygame or py2exe, so I can't say what is better for your usecase. If the target machine has python and pip available, you could package your program using an setup.py file, pack it in a .zip file and install it with `pip install my-cool-game.zip`. You could add pygame as an requirement, so pip installs it automatically. But if your usecase does not allow that, don't do it this way ;)

Comment: I did a couple of dozen of pygame projects with Pyinstaller. It worked just fine for me. You should pay atention that relative paths are correct, and to include `-w` parameter when making `.exe` which means it will run without a console. If you are using GUI such as pygame you will want this. Also make sure that pygame is up to date especially if you use Python 3.8. pygame 2.0.0.dev6 should not cause any errors or misbehaviour.

Comment: Another tip, before converting desired file rename it to `main.py` if you decide to work with Pyinstaller